# How to use trained yolov7 best.pt file as "vehicle plate detection" application in python?

Tags: yolo, yolov5

I have trained a model using yolov7 https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1X9A8odmK4k6l26NDviiT6dd6TgR-piOa#scrollTo=nD-uPyQ_2jiN colab file. After training I got a file named best.pt and I want to use it as a service/application in python. There is a yolov3 example which I created. This one was using .weights so how can I use .pt?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import os


def getPhoto():
    ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    URL = "http://192.168.1.3:4747/video"
    PC_CAM = 0
    net = cv2.dnn.readNet(
        f"{ROOT_DIR}\\yolov3_custom_final.weights",
        f"{ROOT_DIR}\\yolov3_custom.cfg",
    )

    classes = []
    with open(f"{ROOT_DIR}\\classes.txt", "r") as f:
        classes = f.read().splitlines()
    timeElapsed = 0
    wCam, hCam = 640, 360

    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
    colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(2, 3))
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(URL)
    cap.set(3, wCam)
    cap.set(4, hCam)

    while True:
        _, img = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow("Detection Screen", img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("c"):
            break

    height, width, _ = img.shape
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(
        img, 1 / 255, (416, 416), (0, 0, 0), swapRB=True, crop=False
    )
    net.setInput(blob)
    output_layers_names = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames()
    layerOutputs = net.forward(output_layers_names)

    boxes = []
    confidences = []
    class_ids = []

    for output in layerOutputs:
        for detection in output:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.6:
                center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
                center_y = int(detection[1] * height)
                w = int(detection[2] * width)
                h = int(detection[3] * height)

                x = int(center_x - w / 2)
                y = int(center_y - h / 2)

                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                confidences.append((float(confidence)))
                class_ids.append(class_id)

    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.2, 0.4)

    if len(indexes) > 0:
        for i in indexes.flatten():
            x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
            label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
            confidence = str(round(confidences[i], 2))
            color = colors[i]
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
            cv2.putText(
                img,
                label + " " + confidence,
                (x, y + 20),
                font,
                2,
                (255, 255, 0),
                2,
            )

    cv2.imwrite(f"{ROOT_DIR}\\DetectedPhoto.jpg", img)
    print("Image Saved")


getPhoto()
```

I want to detect vehicle plates using .pt file and cut vehicle plates and save them as .jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with detect.py insided yolov7 folder. Run this:

```
python detect.py --weights best.pt --source image.jpg
```

you can download yolov7 with this method:

```
git clone https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7.git
```

in yolov7 you can see detect.py

Comment: I'm telling you that I want to use my .pt file as a service so I don't want to just call it from console. Also I checked detect.py but that is so complicated. Can you send a basic detect.py example?